# R Interpolate values

Tags: r, interpolation

I have to pairs of values:

```
A    B
211  2
19   1
```

How can I interpolate B for the value A=132?

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with R.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: Since you only have two points, your best bet is linear interpolation. What's stopping you, exactly?

Answer (score 7):

Using `approx` (linear interpolation):

```
grid <- data.frame(A = c(211, 19), B = c(2, 1))
grid
#     A B
# 1 211 2
# 2  19 1

approx(x = grid$A, y = grid$B, xout = 132)
# $x
# [1] 132
# 
# $y
# [1] 1.588542
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to model a straight line between these points:

```
predict(lm(B~A),newdata=list(A=132))
       1 
1.588542
```